# Visual Studio use old URL to TFS server

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have problem with bad url to TFS 2010 server in Visual Studio.

First I have TFS 2010 on machine zeus... TFS url was zeus:8080\tfs

Then changed location, now is TFS on machine hades...TFS url is now hades:8080\tfs

In visual studio I changed source control to  hades:8080\tfs.

Then I created Team project in Team collection.

When I am trying add some solution to source control Visual Studio still use old TFS url (zeus:8080\tfs).

I don't know how can I change it. I search in Visual Studio some settings when I can configure TFS url.

But actually I am connected with good TFS url. I can add Team project to TFS collection but when I am trying add solution Visual Studio use old URL.

Any advice.

Answer (score 4):

Did you try to [clear your cache](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2009/07/06/Clear-the-cache-of-TFS.aspx)?

Did you follow the steps in the [MSDN article: Move Team Foundation Server from One Hardware Configuration to Another](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms404869%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)?